# Alias and multiple names for attributes

Tags: eiffel

Defining various names for a same feature seems possible in Eiffel, what for the attributes?

Is it possible to name an attribute like:

```
background, bk: COLOR
foreground, fg: COLOR
```

If not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eiffel
    background, bk: COLOR

is the same as

```
background: COLOR
bk: COLOR
```

(same convention for local variables, arguments, ...)

To have a kind of alias on an attribute, you may do

```
background: COLOR assign set_background
bk: COLOR assign set_background
   do
      Result := background
   end
set_background (c: COLOR)
   do
       background := c
   end
```

Side note: for function and procedure ... even if it looks an alias

```
foo, bar: STRING 
  do 
    Result := "abc" 
  end
```

In fact, `bar` is not an alias for `foo`, they are two different features.
In descendant, you can rename, redefine one or the other independently.

There is no notion of such alias name in Eiffel. The only concept of alias is used to have operator such as `plus alias "+" (s: READABLE_STRING_GENERAL): like Current` in class STRING_32 .
Or also in HASH_TABLE `item alias "[]"`

Comment: Thx, thats a workaround :-( I didn't know the assign keyword! maybe it could be nice to add some words about that on this post... Why isn't it possible to declare multiple names for the same attribute? as some of the concepts is that a function and attribute is the same for the client???

Comment: I edited my answer to add note about what you think is "alias" on feature.

Comment: There is no notion of such alias name in Eiffel. The only concept of alias is used to have operator such as 
    ` plus alias "+" (s: READABLE_STRING_GENERAL): like Current `
 in class STRING_32